# NERDTree with AG.vim after "e" cursor goes to NERDTree - vim

Tags: vim, nerdtree, ag

I have **NERDTree** opened on the default left side, and some **vim** file on the right side. After I do search with **Ag** like **:Ag! "echo"** I get results in the **quickfix** window. I chose one of the results and by pressing "**e**" it opens it to the right side and close the **quickfix** window, but cursor goes to the left side where the **NERDTree** is located. Is there a way to jump to opened file right after I click "**e**" and not pressing "**ctrl+w**" and "**l**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same setup (NERDTree and Ag) and hadn’t noticed this behavior. My workflow is to open a file and then open NERDTree (or vice versa), then Ag at some point. And pressing `Enter` or `e` just took me to the line in the file, as expected. The key is that I **have some file already open**.

I can reproduce the problem you’re seeing by firing up Vim with no file, then opening NERDTree, then running Ag. So a workaround is to have some file open first -- not just an empty Vim with NERDTree open.

The workaround is pretty, uh, workable. It’s already natural to open and close NERDTree frequently. A useful mapping for this is:

```
nmap <Leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

An alternative mnemonic would be `<Leader>e` for *Explore*. And while we’re at it:

```
nmap <Leader>g :Ag!<CR>
```

So the sequence to grep (if you have NERDTree open but no buffer open) is simply `,n,g` (assuming your leader is `,`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your awesome help. Gonna use <Leader> Again, thank you man.